# how to integrate external aar sdk into my react native application

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle, aar

How to integrate an .aar library into a react native application
I have an external library in .aar and i want to integrate it into my react native application
I followed these instructions :

1. I put the aar file into android/app/libs
2. added the following line
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar']).  Into build.gradle

The problem is i don't understand how to use it in my app , what's the name to import with native modules in react native ? Am i missing something with the integration process ? how can i use the library in my react native components ?

```
const MyLibrary = NativeModules.mylibrary
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';

module.exports = NativeModules.mylibrary;
```